# Extracting kernel density estimates to a new sample points in R

Tags: r, spatial, kernel-density, spatstat

I have spatial referenced data (shapefiles) of 400 polygons and points that are spread over them. I wish to create a raster of kernel density estimate for each polygon based on the points it contains. After that, I want to create a sample of 100 random points for each polygon, where each point has a spatial reference (x and y coordinates) and a kde value. All I managed to do until now was to create a kde image in the shape of the polygons using the 'ppp.density' function, but the output comes out different than the one described in the document and I don't know in what format it is and how to obtain the kde values to a sample of new points.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
buffer <- st_read(".../.././buffers.shp")
pbb<- st_read(".../.../.././pbb.shp")

 library(spatstat)
 
 for (p in 1:400) {
  if(p %in% pbb$value) {
    poly123<- pbb[pbb$value == p,]
    
    C <- as.owin(buffer$geometry[p])
    point<- ppp(poly123$X,poly123$Y, window = C)
    d <- density(point, kernel = "gaussian")
    plot(d)
```

[kde plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqzV.png)

[The 'density' output is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbokZ.png)

Comment: To be sure I understand: You want to generate 100 random points in each polygon and evaluate the KDE at each of the 100 locations? This can be done very easily with spatstat. Can't write details right now from my phone.

Comment: Yes, I want to first create the kde raster based on real observations (points within different polygons), and than create  new random samples of 100 points for each polygon where each point will have a kde value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the function `density.ppp` (not "ppp.density") from the `spatstat` package.

If `p` is a point pattern (class `ppp`) then `D <- density(p)` computes the unnormalised kernel density estimate. See `help(density.ppp)` for explanation and examples.

The result `D` is a pixel image (class `im`) which can be printed, plotted and subsetted, etc. (In your question you have just printed the internal structure of the `im` object.)

After computing the pixel image `D`, if you want to know the values of `D` at some spatial locations, then you could

- make the query locations into a point pattern `X`, then extract the numerical values at those locations by `values <- D[X]` ; or
- convert the pixel image to a function by `f <- as.function(D)` then evaluate the function at desired coordinates `x,y` by `values <- f(x,y)`.

If you want to know the density values at the *original* data locations `p`, then it is faster and more accurate to use the `at` argument to `density.ppp`:

```
values <- density(p, at="points")
```

Warning: In your example (and the examples above), the smoothing bandwidth `sigma` was not specified. The default value of `sigma` may be unsatisfactory for your data. See the help file and examples for `density.ppp`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked great. Also, thank you for the comment regarding the sigma. I will look into that.